# Golang странная работа кода

Tags: golang

я решил сделать мини яп и почему-то в кавычках когда я вызываю `\"` не видит закрывающую скобочку в конце.
Вот код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main(){
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("PointLang error: you not enter file name.")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("PointLang error:", err) 
        os.Exit(1) 
    }
    defer file.Close() 
     
    data := make([]byte, 64)
    n, err := file.Read(data)
    if err == io.EOF{   // если конец файла
        os.Exit(1)      // выходим из цикла
    }
    str := string(data[:n])
    currentString := strings.Split(str, "\n")
     
    for i := 0; i < len(currentString); i++ {
        if strings.HasPrefix(currentString[i], "println") {
            arg := currentString[i][7:]
            if strings.HasPrefix(arg, "(") || strings.HasPrefix(arg, " ("){
                if strings.HasPrefix(arg, "("){ 
                    arg = arg[1:]
                } else {
                    arg = arg[2:]
                }
                symb := strings.Split(arg, "")
                output := ""
                textedR := false
                endStr := 0
                for j := 0; j < len(symb); j++ {
                    if symb[j] == ")" && textedR == false {
                        endStr = 1
                        break
                    } else if symb[j] == "\"" {
                        if textedR {
                            textedR = false
                        } else {
                            textedR = true
                        }
                    } else if symb[j] == "\\" && textedR == true {
                        j += 1
                        if symb[j] == "\"" {
                            output += symb[j]
                        }
                    } else if textedR {
                        output += symb[j]
                    }
                }
                if endStr == 0 {
                    fmt.Println("PointLang error on line ", i+1 ,": you forgot \")\" to end the function")
                    os.Exit(1)
                }
                fmt.Println(output)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("PointLang error on line ", i+1 ,": you forgot \"(\" to start the function")
                os.Exit(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

в коде скрипта самого языка

```
println("hello world")
println("test\"")
```

Comment: непонятно. Что означает не видит? Что должно быть? Что происходит на самом деле?

Comment: он пишет в консоле

Comment: hello world
PointLang error on line 2: you forgot \")\" to end the function

Comment: а должно
hello world
test "

Comment: В примере, который вы тут привели всё ok. Возможно ваша проблема в другой части кода, которую вы не включили в вопрос. Или данные у вас другие.

Comment: я весь код скинул

Comment: @Daniilus а данные (код скрипта самого языка)? То, что есть, выводит `hello world`
`test"`. Попробуйте создать новый проект из того кода, что вы прислали и запустить его. Кстати как вы запускаете? А версия go какая?

Comment: go version 1.16.5